# angular send data to view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have a link in

as this

```
<li ng-repeat="x in data"> <a ng-href="/myurl#/view">{{x.id}}</a> </li>
```

I want to send x.id to myurl controller.

here is my router

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/myurl',
            {
                templateUrl:"url.html",
                controller:"UrlController"
            }
        )
        .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/find'
        });
});
```

this is where I would like to have then new passed x.id value

```
app.controller("UrlController", function($scope, $http){

//need vlaue here in scope

 });
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables through URLs in the router, for example:

link:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in data"> <a ng-href="#/myurl/{{x.id}}">{{x.id}}</a> </li>
```

router:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/myurl/:id',
        {
            templateUrl:"url.html",
            controller:"UrlController"
        }
    )
    .when('/myurl',
        {
            templateUrl:"url.html",
            controller:"UrlController"
        }
    )
    .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/find'
    });
});
```

controller:

```
app.controller("UrlController", function($scope, $routeParams, $http){

    if (angular.isDefined($routeParams.id)) {
        var id = $routeParams.id;
    }

});
```

Comment: that send me back to my default route ../find

Comment: @Autolycus you have to have the id in the URL, or alternatively have a fallback for a URL without an id

Comment: @Autolycus updated answer to show a fallback for no id